# Parent Fragment communication with fragment inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

- I have one `MainActivity` with -> `FragmentA` which contains -> `ViewPager` with (`Fragment1,Fragment2,Fragment3`)
- Now in `FragmentA` I have one spinner and any selection must reflect the changes inside **viewpager's** currently visible fragment.
- How can I achieve that? I don't want to follow `ViewModel` or `EventBus` approach for now as I am working on very old project. I want to use interface to communicate between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `interface` inside your `FragmentA`

```
interface OnSpinnerValue{
    fun onSpinnerValueChanged()
}
```

Create a `WeakReference` for the current selected `fragment`

```
private var _currentPage: WeakReference<OnSpinnerValue>? = null
private val currentPage
    get() = _currentPage?.get()

fun setCurrentPage(page: OnSpinnerValue) {
    _currentPage = WeakReference(page)
}
```

Now implement this `interface` in every child `fragment` of `ViewPager`

```
class Fragment1() : Fragment(), OnAddEvent {
    override fun onSpinnerValueChanged() {
         // implement your method
    }
}
```

And, update `currentPage` value of the `FragmentA`, according to the selected fragment, and update it in `onResume()` of each child `fragment`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (parentFragment as FragmentA).setCurrentPage(this)
}
```

Now, trigger `onSpinnerValueChanged` from your spinner's `onItemSelected` methods

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
     currentPage?.onSpinnerValueChanged()
}
```

Comment: Why do we use WeakReference here?

Comment: So that it doesn't lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange if you don't want to use ViewModel ,
I know may be it is not best solutions but you can :

1. you can create function itIsYourFunctionToUpdate() inside your fragment and update him on `FragmentA()` , calling function with her object like `fragmentB.itIsYourFunctionToUpdate()`
   or

> ```
> if (ViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 && page != null) {
>           ((FragmentClass1)page).itIsYourFunctionToUpdate("new item");     
>      }
> ```

2. Also you can update viewPager like this  `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and all fragment inside viewPager must be updated